# How to construct the covariance function from the fdd of a centered Gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, covariance

I have a  **centered** Gaussian process $\mathbb G=(G_t)_{t\geq0}$, for which I don't have the covariance function $\Sigma_{s,t}$.

I know that the process is uniquely determined by the mean function, for which we have here $m(t)=0$ and $\Sigma_{s,t}$.

On the other hand a stochastic process is uniquely determined by its finite dimensional distributions, which are for $n\in\mathbb N$, $t^*=({t_1},\ldots,{t_n})\in\mathbb R^n_+$ arbitrary the distributions of the following vector
$$
X^n_{t^*}=(X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n})
$$ 
In my case I know how they are distributed. Each component $X_{t_1}\sim N(0,\sigma^2_{t_1})$ and the joint distribution $X^n_{t^*}\sim N(0,\sigma^2_{\sum_{i=1}^nt_i}) $ while 
$$
\sigma^2_{t_1}=\int_{\mathbb R} \left(f(t_1)\right)^2(x) \;dP(x)
$$
where I omitted some details (actually the integral is about a sum of two Fourier transforms, which are in fact linear). The important thing here I guess is that $f$ is linear.

From this I actually should be able to construct the covariance function but I just couldn't manage it so far. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it:

As a matter of fact, it's straight forward thinking, I simply computed the variance of 
$$
\sigma^2_{t_1+t_2}=\int_{\mathbb R} \left(f(t_1+t_2)\right)^2 \;dP(x)
$$
which gave me all information I was seeking, since this turned out to be (f is linear in $t_i$)
$$
\sigma^2_{t_1+t_2}=\sigma^2_{t_1}+\sigma^2_{t_2}+2\int_{\mathbb R} \left(f(t_1)f(t_2)\right)(x) \;dP(x)
$$
and because of the fact that 
$$
Var(X_1+X_2)=\sigma^2_{X_1}+\sigma^2_{X_2}+2Cov(X_1,X_2)
$$
we have 
$$
Cov(X_1,X_2)=\int_{\mathbb R} \left(f(t_1)f(t_2)\right)(x) \;dP(x)
$$
and are done.